# The word bibliopolium means a bookstore?

Tags: vocabulary

I have been trying out Rosetta Stone's Latin instruction program, which is kind of interesting because it attempts to teach modern conversational Latin, as though it were a living language, which is obviously completely different than the usual emphasis on classical literature found in most scholastic Latin programs.

One of the many modernistic Latin words I have learned in this program is *bibliopolium*, which apparently means bookstore. What is the precedent for this word? I cannot find it in Latin dictionaries and the word polium does not mean store as far as I am aware. I would have expected bookstore to be *taberna libraria* or something like that. Also, they call a pharmacy a *pharmacopolium*, so it seems to be following the same pattern. Is it some kind of medieval word?

Answer (score 3):

It's from the Greek βιβλιοπωλεῖον. The first element is βιβλίον (*biblion*, "book") and the second element is from πωλεῖν (*pōlein* "to sell").

There is an attested Latin word [*bibliopola*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dbibliopola), from the Greek βιβλιοπώλης, both of which mean *bookseller*. *Bibliopolium* then is just a Latinized version of βιβλιοπωλεῖον, which is legitimate enough since a closely related word existed in Classical Latin (and is found in later texts).

Interestingly, [Aulus Gellius](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DL%3Aentry+group%3D22%3Aentry%3Dlibrarius2) uses *libraria* for a bookshop, which I probably would have preferred over a what I think is a [Neo-Latin coinage](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Athelatinlibrary.com+%22bibliopolia%22&t=ffab&ia=web) (though maybe someone can find it in some Late Antique or Medieval text).

Comment: The same entry in Short that you give cites taberna libraria in Cicero, just as I had guessed in my question.

Comment: @TylerDurden Yep, you weren't wrong. I remember taking Rosetta Stone's Latin course sampler about 20 years ago. I wonder how it is now.